# Time Out Exception for all requests in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to stop the services after 30Sec.
Here I'm using SpringBoot application and it has many Rest API's. Default time out is 60Sec in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Set this property in application.properties

```
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=30s
```

You can find all configuration properties of Spring Boot in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties